# how to use Two For loop (not nested loop)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I wan to print Student data and Class data. So, I wrote a code to fetch Student_id and Class_id.

- Firstly the Input Student_id must match with the Stud_id in Student_data.csv file and print the data according.[I found the answer for this]
- Samely, the input class_id must match with the Class_id in Class_data.csv file and print the data according.

I need the Final output as below[marked in **]:

Option 8: Enrol a student to a class
Enter student id: S001
Enter class id: C001

- Student S001, Kitty Tan enrolled into class C001, CCW101, Computer and Information Processing *

Code:

```
if option == 8:

            Stud_id = str(input("Enter Student Id : ")).lower()
            Clas_id = str(input("Enter Class ID : ")).lower()

            Stud_File=open('Student_Data.csv', "r")                             ## Reading CSV file.
            Stud_Reader=list(csv.reader(Stud_File, delimiter=','))            ## Converting the csv file into List.
            Class_File=open('Class_Data.csv', "r")                             ## Reading CSV file.
            Class_Reader=list(csv.reader(Stud_File, delimiter=','))            ## Converting the csv file into List.

            for row in Stud_Reader:                                               ## Creating a for loop to search sub-string in a string in a CSV file data.
                    for field in row:                                
                            if Stud_id in field:                                        
                                    print("Student " +Stud_id), row[1],(" Enrolled into Class " +Clas_id)


            for row in Class_Reader:
                    for field in row:
                            if Clas_id in field:
                                    print(row[1], row[2])
```

Student S001, Kitty Tan enrolled into class C001, CCW101, Computer and Information Processing *

Comment: Can you describe what your code is doing incorrectly?

Comment: `Class_Reader=list(csv.reader(Stud_File, delimiter=','))` should probably be reading from the `Class_File`.

Comment: Its a Class management system project. After selecting the option 8 it will enroll the student to class. and it will print the output as below Student S001, Kitty Tan enrolled into class C001, CCW101, Computer and Information Processing *

Answer (score 1):

If you give the design of the .csv i guess you can use Pandas to make the access simpler. But i guess just store the string and print it later. and use break to end for when you found your student id.

Comment: Pandas seems to be very heavy topic for me as Im a newbie. Please help me with the code.

Comment: I guess your question is already answered in Zhenhirs Post below.
save the information needed in first loop, like `studInfo = 'Student ' + str(Stud_id) + str(row[1])`
`break`
and then use print in second loop like
`print(studInfo + ' Enrolled into Class ' + str(Clas_id) + str(row[1]) + ',' + str(row[2]))`
`break`

Comment: yes but still facing some issue with the second loop. rectifyin the same.

Comment: Sorry but it is quite difficult help you like this, maybe share the data you are loading or a sample.
I guess you are running into an Exception, or the Class ID is not found

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it almost does what you want.. but you can store the student text "Student S001, Kitty Tan enrolled into class C001" in a variable and just print it later.. you could also try using `end=""` in your first `print` statement, which would stop it from printing a newline.. but I don't think that's as good a way to do this and it's only do-able in python3.

```
        Stud_id = str(input("Enter Student Id : ")).lower()
        Clas_id = str(input("Enter Class ID : ")).lower()

        Stud_File=open('Student_Data.csv', "r")                             ## Reading CSV file.
        Stud_Reader=list(csv.reader(Stud_File, delimiter=','))            ## Converting the csv file into List.
        Class_File=open('Class_Data.csv', "r")                             ## Reading CSV file.
        Class_Reader=list(csv.reader(Class_File, delimiter=','))            ## Converting the csv file into List.

        for row in Stud_Reader:                                               ## Creating a for loop to search sub-string in a string in a CSV file data.
                for field in row:                                
                        if Stud_id in field:                                        
                                student_text = "Student " + Stud_id + row[1] + " Enrolled into Class " + Clas_id


        for row in Class_Reader:
                for field in row:
                        if Clas_id in field:
                                print(student_text, row[1], row[2])
```

Comment: please rectify the code, as im a newbie in python. its is my college project.

Comment: He is just printing the string student_text in the last printing statement, so all wanted information gets out in one line. Besides that your solution and his is basically the same.

Comment: All the changes you should need are already in the code I posted above.. Did something not work?

Comment: Its not entering into second loop. it shows no output. returning back to main menu.

Answer (score 0):

if you give your sample csv, it will be faster to understand. Below will work for your problem.

```py
def check_student_id(student_id):
    try:
        Stud_File = open('Student_Data.csv', "r")
        Stud_Reader = list(csv.reader(Stud_File, delimiter=','))
        for stud_id_row in Stud_Reader:
            for stud_id in stud_id_row:
                if str(stud_id).lower() == student_id:
                    return True
        return False
    except Exception as Err:
        print(str(Err))
        return False


def check_class_id(class_id):
    try:
        Class_File = open('Class_Data.csv', "r")
        Class_Reader = list(csv.reader(Class_File, delimiter=','))
        for class_id_row in Class_Reader:
            for cls_id in class_id_row:
                if str(cls_id).lower() == class_id:
                    return True
        return False
    except Exception as Err:
        print(str(Err))
        return False

Stud_id = str(input("Enter Student Id : ")).lower()
Clas_id = str(input("Enter Class ID : ")).lower()

is_student_id_exists = check_student_id(Stud_id)
if is_student_id_exists:
    is_class_id_exits = check_class_id(Clas_id)
    if is_class_id_exits:
        print("Student {}, Enrolled into Class {}".format(Stud_id, Clas_id))
    else:
        print("Class id doesnt exits.")
else:
    print("Student id doesnt exits.")
```

if you CSV have data of student ID and class registered then we need to retrieve that data to show. But what i assume for you question is "Need to validate student ID and class ID present before proceeding to enrolling"